# Thymeleaf. Building table from array & list

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

I got this code:

```
<th:block th:if="${!#lists.isEmpty(partyInfoByUploaderList)}" th:each="pInfo : ${partyInfoByUploaderList}">
<h4 th:text="${pInfo.getCharName()}"></h4>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th:block th:if="${!#lists.isEmpty(pInfo.getCharColumnTitles())}" th:each="title: ${pInfo.getCharColumnTitles()}">
                <td th:text="${title}"></td>
            </th:block>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th:block th:each="val: ${pInfo.getCharColumnValues()}">
                <td th:text="${val}"></td>
            </th:block>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I got this result:
http://screenshot.ru/6dfbe559f905a17dff44d360b5d13f28

So this code correctly create table head, and dont parse table body.
BTW, after delpoy this code appear at another place:

```
<th:block th:each="val: ${pInfo.getCharColumnValues()}">
     <td th:text="${val}"></td>
</th:block>
```

Web source code in browser:
http://screenshot.ru/9d3fab8030c5ca382ab81094e0c1ca86

Question #2:
Why this code produce TemplateProcessingException error?

P.S. Not enough reputation for images, so just links. Soz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Thymeleaf Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag), `<th:block></th:block>` should wrap `<tr></tr>` and not the opposite. So you should try this :

```
<th:block th:each="val: ${pInfo.getCharColumnValues()}">
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${val}"></td>
    </tr>
</th:block>
```